# Acceleration down an inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

> A sled slides down an icy slope starting at 6.14m/s. At the bottom of the slope its speed is 12.5m/s. What is the minimum height of the slope?

Why does this question ask for minimum height?

Comment: "Why does this question ask for minimum height?" Can you elucidate?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to use energy conservation. Since we are dealing with an icy slope, the energy losses due to friction will be minimal but maybe not exactly zero. If we assume that they are exactly zero, we get a minimum height which is necessary for the sled to reach the given velocity of 12.5m/s. If we have some energy losses, the height will have to be higher.